# how can i bring to uniform format tel. number

Tags: java, regex

how can i bring to uniform format tel. number?
using only regex

it can be +79998887766 or 8 999 8887766 or 8-999-888-77-66 etc.

but i need only +7 999 888-77-66

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Input your phone number: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number = in.nextLine();
```

what's next?

Comment: There is no single uniform phone number format. Every country has their own format.

Comment: `number = number.replaceFirst("^\\+?7[ -]?(\\d{3})[ -]?(\\d{3})[ -]?(\\d{2})[ -]?(\\d{2})$", "+7 $1 $2-$3-$4");` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HQxomu/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your three different formats of mobile numbers, you can reformat it to the common one you mentioned `+7 999 888-77-66` by first capturing the numbers into five groups of numbers using following regex,

```
^\D*(\d)\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*$
```

And then replace it with,

```
+$1 $2 $3-$4-$5
```

To restore the number in desired format.

[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClaPDE/1)

Java code demo,

```
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("+79998887766", "8 999 8887766", "8-999-888-77-66");
    numbers.forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.replaceAll("^\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d{3})\\D*(\\d{3})\\D*(\\d{2})\\D*(\\d{2})\\D*$", "+$1 $2 $3-$4-$5"));
    });
```

Output,

```
+79998887766 --> +7 999 888-77-66
8 999 8887766 --> +8 999 888-77-66
8-999-888-77-66 --> +8 999 888-77-66
```

Comment: That format is only valid for a `+7` country prefix, so the regex should limit itself to that.

Comment: @Andreas: Not sure what all countries he wants to cover, but I've covered the three different input formats. Unless he provides more different formats including different country codes, and desired final formatted number, it will be hard to generalise the solution but my solution covers for what all he mentioned.